# Insert Multiple Files Data into a Worksheet in Row Increment

Tags: excel, vba

Warmest greeting, currently I have a template in my Excel worksheet.
What am I doing is actually loop through multiple folders, in each folder consist of multiple files, compare the data and get the result. The result come out in this way [Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtCun.jpg) The outcome is the result after comparing all the files in all folders.

What I am looking is, when it loop to a new folder, the result will be show with row offset by 9. This mean by every folders will show one set of result. [Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRVyk.jpg)

This is the code I wrote to loop through every folder:

```
Sub SearchReport()

    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks("List Folder Name.xlsm").Worksheets("Main Menu").Activate
    counter = 2
    Do While Range("A" & counter).Value <> ""   'do when Range A is not empty (folder path)

        If Range("C" & counter).Value = "Yes" Then  'check Range C, do when Range C = Yes
            HostFolder = Range("A" & counter).Value & "\"
            Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Report FileSystem.getFolder(HostFolder) 'HostFolder is the folder path from Range A
            counter = counter + 1
        Else
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub Report(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim subfld As Folder
    Dim subfldr As Folder
    Dim File As File
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim Wksht As Worksheet
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim N As Long


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

           For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders  'loop through subfolders in the  first folder path
            If SubFolder.Name = "Report" Then 'look for a folder named "Report"

                MyPath = SubFolder.Path & "\"
                fileName = Dir(MyPath & "*al.dat")  'look for files which is ended with "al.dat" in the "Report" folder


                  Do While Len(fileName) > 0    'open the files

                    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & fileName)
                    Set Wrksht = wbk.Worksheets(1)

                    find

                    wbk.Close True
                    fileName = Dir

                  Loop

           Else
            Sheets("Main Menu").Activate
            Report SubFolder
           End If
           Next

End Sub
```

And during the data process, I set the result to be insert in this way:

```
With Workbooks("List Folder Name.xlsm").Sheets("Result")
.Range("D7").Value = H
.Range("A7").Value = HX
.Range("B7") = HY
.Range("C7") = HY2
End With
```

Is there any way to get my desired outcome? I hope I could get some help or advice, any effort is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code of yours allows output only to row 7:

```
With Workbooks("List Folder Name.xlsm").Sheets("Result")
.Range("A7").Value = HX
.Range("B7") = HY
.Range("C7") = HY2
.Range("D7").Value = H
End With
```

It seems to me that you need to replace it with code that, perhaps starts at row 7 but then offsets the row by 9 each time. This is done using the `.offset()` function applied to the range where `r.offset(x,y)` means offset by `x` rows and `y` columns.  This is just a start at the code. I suggest that you step through it to understand and then modify as needed:

```
dim r as range, sh as worksheet, i as integer, numberOfEntries as integer
set sh = Workbooks("List Folder Name.xlsm").Sheets("Result")
set r= sh.range("A6")
For i = 0 to numberOfEntries 
With sh
  r.offset(i*9,0) = "file name"
  r.offset(i*9+1,0) = HX
  r.offset(i*9,1) = "spur freq"
  r.offset(i*9+1,1) = HY
  r.offset(i*9,2) = "spur.."
  r.offset(i*9+1,2) = HY2
  r.offset(i*9,3) = "margin"
  r.offset(i*9+1,3) = H
end with
next i
```

Comment: I've now added more code to provide the colored headings as well as the data below each heading.  The idea is that after each loop, it then offsets the row by 9, but stays in the same columns

Comment: Hi, thanks for your guidance, may I ask what is the "numberOfEntries" refers to? number of folder or number of file? Sorry I am quite n00b in Excel VBA

Comment: numberOfEntries is the number of times thru the for..next loop. Each time thru, 2 rows are being made, your colored headings & the data beneath them.  As I wrote, this is just a start at the code, and I suggest you step thru it (Debug-->Step Into), to watch what it does so you understand the concept.  Then, you can modify as needed for your situation. You may not want a for...next loop, but instead a do...loop until, While...wend, etc... or maybe no loop at all if this part of the code is a function called repeatedly from an another loop. I just put a for..next loop here for demo purposes

Comment: Sorry for slow reply since I spent some time to understand the function! Thanks for your advise and help!